# Magento : Backend Model, Save Multiselect Attribute when condition is matched

Tags: product-attribute, model, backend, multiselect-attribute

I am trying to customize an extension (Customer Groups Catalog 2 = http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-groups-catalog2.html),

It has a multiselect attribute (groupscatalog2_groups) of product in which admin can assign customer groups to product, and when i checked it in admin it doesn't have any option.

It has `source`, `backend` and `frontend` model assigned in `addAttribute` in mysql script.

Now, in backend model, it has `beforeSave`, `afterSave` and `afterLoad` method which handles saving and displaying that attribute options.

I want to set that attribute when a condition is matched in frontend, is it possible to do so ?

I tried `$prdctModel->addData()` method as we generally do for multiselect attribute, but it's not working.

Any Suggestions ?